# R - Slicing a matrix in R column wise in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix `bigDaddy` of dimensions `nrow=20, ncol=1000`. Now I have a `for` loop where I want to run 100 iterations and in each iteration, I want to get a slice of 10 columns and all rows of `bigDaddy`. e.g. in first iteration, all rows and columns 1-10, in second iteration all rows and columns 11-20 and so on.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to 991, by=10))
{
    smallChild <- bigDaddy[,i:i+9]
}
```

but what's `smallChild` giving me in first iteration is a 20 length vector created from 10th column of matrix `bigDaddy`. If i hardcode the value of i in the code like `smallChild <- bigDaddy[,1:10]`, I get the expected matrix.

Can someone point me to the correct direction?

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis, `i:(i+9)`. Also, you are reassigning values to `SmallChild` over and over again. When the loop ends you will only have the last iteration one.

Comment: Thanks Rui, you are right. Coming from a non-R programming background, I feel R is hopeless now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign` to save each SmallChild under a different name, e.g. SmallChild1, SmallChild11, etc.

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to 991, by=10))
{
    temp <- bigDaddy[,i:(i+9)]
    assign(paste0(SmallChild, i), temp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `lapply` to save a list of objects as opposed to many separate (similarly structured) objects:

```
data_list <- lapply(seq(from=1, to=991, by=10), function(i) bigDaddy[,i:(i+9)])
```

Even give the items names:

```
data_list <- setNames(data_list, paste0("SmallChild_", seq(length(data_list))))

data_list$SmallChild_1
data_list$SmallChild_2
data_list$SmallChild_3
...
```

And if you really want separate objects run `list2env` on a named list of objects:

```
list2env(data_list, .GlobalEnv)
```